# Get-FolderItem convert output

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am using the `get-folderitem` command that uses robocopy and the output that is produced is `@{parentfolder = folder name1} @{parentfolder = folder name2}`  how can i turn this into an array with just the folder names so `[folder name1, folder name2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting there is a list of objects with the property `parentfolder`. Expand the property to get its values:

```
Get-FolderItem ... | Select-Object -Expand parentfolder
```